# Extract all the data matching patterns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract the data from pandas dataframe column w.r.t the pattern but getting only the first match.

1. How can we align the pandas dataframe column(txt)  into a single line for regextractall usage
2. How to extract all the data that matches the pattern [*].[*] from pandas column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'txt': ["sample text  [EN1].[attrgs] 
            when x=1 then 1 
            else [EN2].[abc]  
            testing [EN3].[BUS]  WHERE [EN1].[attrgs] = abc"]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['txt'])

df['txt'].str.findall(r'\[.*\]').str.join(", ")
```

Required output:

[EN1].[attrgs],[EN2].[abc],[EN3].[BUS]

Comment: `r'\[.*?\]'` with the non-greedy `*?`. And to get exactly your example (text between brackets - dot - text between brackets), it should be `r'\[.*?\].\[.*?\]'`

Comment: Thank you, For some of the records, I see this regex bringing the data with patterns xxx[].[] 
and also for some records this is bringing data from [] instead of [].[]

Comment: Can you shown an example for each case? [It works for me](https://regex101.com/r/cOoBNo/1).

Comment: Examples of source data, basically need the data between [].[] and strip any before or after these brackets.
abc.[id] = hello [zy].[COL].trim + "abc and 

[sample])  = UPPER([txn].[book

cons [[text].[id2] = [pro].[id5] and]

Comment: 1. abc.[id] = hello [zy].[COL].trim + "abc and 

2. [sample])  = UPPER([txn].[book

3. cons [[text].[id2] = [pro].[id5] and]

Comment: The characters inside brackets are always alphanumeric? If so, you can use [`\[\w*?\].\[\w*?\]`](https://regex101.com/r/fNUuEa/1).